# Recursion In Oracle

Tags: oracle, recursion

I have the following table in an oracle:

```
Parent(arg1, arg2)
```

and I want the transitive closure of the relation parent. That is, I want the following table

```
Ancestor(arg1, arg2)
```

How is this possible in Oracle?

I am doing the following:

```
WITH Ancestor(arg1, arg2)  AS (

  SELECT p.arg1, p.arg2 from parent p
  UNION
  SELECT p.arg1 , a.arg2 from parent p,  Ancestor a 
  WHERE p.arg2 = a.arg1

)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Ancestor;
```

I get the error

```
*Cause:    column aliasing in WITH clause is not supported yet
*Action:   specify aliasing in defintion subquery and retry
Error at Line: 1 Column: 20
```

How can I solve this without column aliasing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
WITH    Ancestor(arg1, arg2) AS
        (
        SELECT  p.arg1, p.arg2
        FROM    parent p
        WHERE   arg2 NOT IN
        (
            SELECT  arg1
            FROM    parent
        )

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  p.arg1, a.arg2
        FROM    Ancestor a 
        JOIN    parent p
        ON      p.arg2 = a.arg1
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    Ancestor
```

`Oracle` only supports recursive `CTE` since `11g` Release 2.

In earlier versions, use `CONNECT BY` clause:

```
SELECT  arg1, CONNECT_BY_ROOT arg2
FROM    parent
START WITH
        arg2 NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  arg1
        FROM    parent
        )
CONNECT BY
        arg2 = PRIOR arg1
```

Comment: 11g Release `2` to be precise

Answer (score 1):

Oracle allows recursive queries.
See: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

Of course, these usually assume the hierarchical data is all in one table. Splitting it into separate tables makes things complicated.