# Oracle sql query to return all records between a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Below is a result of a table ordered by start_time,

```
START_TIME                START_LOCATION_ID END_TIME               END_LOCATION_ID
------------------------- -------------- ------------------------- ------------ 
16/05/2014 12:15:00 am    1              16/05/2014 12:20:00 am    2          
16/05/2014 12:25:00 am    2              16/05/2014 12:30:00 am    3          
16/05/2014 12:35:00 am    3              16/05/2014 12:40:00 am    1          
16/05/2014 12:45:00 am    1              16/05/2014 12:50:00 am    6          
16/05/2014 12:55:00 am    6              16/05/2014 01:00:00 am    7          
16/05/2014 01:05:00 am    7              16/05/2014 01:10:00 am    1          
16/05/2014 01:15:00 am    1              16/05/2014 01:20:00 am    2          
16/05/2014 01:25:00 am    2              16/05/2014 01:30:00 am    4          
16/05/2014 01:35:00 am    4              16/05/2014 01:40:00 am    3          
16/05/2014 01:45:00 am    3              16/05/2014 01:50:00 am    1
```

I need to filter as the output looks like follows if the input is given as start_location_id = 1 and end_location_id = 3.

```
START_TIME                START_LOCATION_ID END_TIME               END_LOCATION_ID
------------------------- -------------- ------------------------- ------------
16/05/2014 12:15:00 am    1              16/05/2014 12:20:00 am    2          
16/05/2014 12:25:00 am    2              16/05/2014 12:30:00 am    3                    
16/05/2014 01:15:00 am    1              16/05/2014 01:20:00 am    2          
16/05/2014 01:25:00 am    2              16/05/2014 01:30:00 am    4         
16/05/2014 01:35:00 am    4              16/05/2014 01:40:00 am    3
```

I don't know how to start querying as I know the condition 'WHERE start_location_id = 1 and end_location_id = 3' won't work as expected.,

Image preview >>[here](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=414003487704)<<

Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please explain the question

Comment: @Ben, Because the requirement is that the result should be in the way that , the starting_point_id with 1 and then all rows and ended by 3 (as the in the input). In the above case the row of 1 and 6, it doesn't ended by any 3. Hope it understood little more clear.

Comment: This is a graph walking problem.  Are you limited in the number of hops?  It is easier to formulate the query if you are only considering 1 or 2 intermediate points.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense...

Comment: Hoof!! , Hope @GordonLinoff understood , I know its a little bit confusing logic, but its just not 1 or 2 intermediate, it may be more. I'll any way make a pictorical representation, ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run it on 12c use the [pattern matching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17749/pattern.htm#DWHSG8960) feature. This gives you exactly the result you want:

```
SELECT * FROM tr
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (ORDER BY start_time
                  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
                  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST FIN
                  PATTERN (STRT MID* FIN)
                  DEFINE
                      STRT AS STRT.start_location_id = 1,
                      MID  AS MID.start_location_id != 1 AND MID.end_location_id != 3,
                      FIN  AS FIN.end_location_id = 3
                 );
```

Here's a solution working in 11g, using analytical functions:

```
SELECT start_time, start_location_id, end_time, end_location_id
  FROM (SELECT tr_groups.*,
               first_value(start_location_id) over (partition by grp order by start_time) strt,
               first_value(end_location_id) over (partition by grp order by start_time desc) fin
          FROM (SELECT tr.*,
                       sum(case when start_location_id in (1, 3) then 1 end) over (order by start_time) grp
                  FROM tr) tr_groups)
 WHERE strt = 1 AND fin = 3;
```

Comment: I added 11g solution, enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is too long for a comment.  What you are asking for seems hard to me.  The solution is going to require a recursive CTE (or a `connect` clause).  You should troll around the internet for examples.  [Here](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html) is a place to start.  Or [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53139879276132) (if you are familiar with `connect`).  Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659803/recursion-in-oracle).

If I understand correctly, your particular problem is harder than others.  Partly, this is because problem is not well-specified.  There are many more than two solutions for getting from 1-->3 in your example.  For instance, there are two paths for 1-->2-->4-->3.  And there is also 1-->2-->3-->1-->2-->4-->3.

How you handle these cases makes a big difference, which is why you need to actually understand the code that you are writing.  This pruning of the cases can be challenging with a recursive CTE, but it is definitely possible.

Comment: thanks for your reply, But if you understood well, You can understand that there is a logic behind it ( but I can't implement and express it), and by the by, there is only one path in the second instance, 1->2->4->3 because it I mentioned in the first sentence that the main result is ordered by start_time.